# Can someone explain this behaviour of the list?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to solve a problem where the updated list doesn't get displayed in my frontend. The list which is displayed is placed in the todo-list component. The new todo button is in the header component.

When I add a new component I call the getToDos method to update the list. From the console the list has been increased by one but when I call the same method from the todo-list component the size hasn't changed. See from this screenshot: https://snag.gy/lNVbX3.jpg

Is this happening as I have created a separate instance of the component and it doesn't affect the supposed list?

If so how am I supposed to do it the right way?

ToDoListComponent:

```
export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {

    todoList: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private dialog: MatDialog) {
    }


    @Input() toDoData = {taskName: '', taskCompleted: false, date: Date};


    ngOnInit() {
        this.getToDos();
    }

    getToDos() {
        this.todoList = [];
        this.todoService.getToDos()
            .subscribe((data: []) => {
                console.log('Todo List get Todos ', data);
                this.todoList = data;
            });
    }

    delete(id) {
        this.todoService.deleteToDo(id)
            .subscribe(res => {
                    this.getToDos();
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }

    completed(id, todo) {
        todo.taskCompleted = !todo.taskCompleted;
        this.todoService.updateToDo(id, todo)
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.getToDos();
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    openDialog(todo): void {
        console.log('TodoList Dialog Open: ', todo);
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditToDoDialogComponent, {
            data: {
                todoUpdate: todo,
            }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
    }

    printList() {
        console.log('print list button', this.todoList);
    }

    callGetToDo() {
        this.getToDos();
    }
}
```

ToDoList html:

```
<button (click)="printList()">Print List</button>
<button (click)="callGetToDo()">Call Method</button>

<mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let todo of todoList">
    <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar>
            <mat-icon [ngClass]="todo.taskCompleted ? 'green' : 'red' ">thumb_up</mat-icon>

        </div>
        <mat-card-title>{{todo.taskName}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>
            <mat-icon style="font-size: 15px">calendar_today</mat-icon>
            {{todo.dueDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <p>
            {{todo.extraNote}}
        </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions align="center">
        <button mat-button (click)="completed(todo.id, todo)">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="!todo.taskCompleted">done</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="todo.taskCompleted">close</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-button (click)="openDialog(todo)">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-button (click)="delete(todo.id)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

HeaderComponent:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    constructor(private todoService: TodoService, private dialog: MatDialog, private todoList: TodoListComponent) {
    }


    openDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewToDoDialogComponent, {});

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('The dialog was closed');
            this.todoList.getToDos();
        });
    }
}
```

HeaderComponent HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-toolbar">
  <span>My ToDo App</span>
  <span class="fill-space"></span>
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">New ToDo</button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I'm very sorry if my question/problem isn't clear.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
Am I supposed to put the list to be displayed in a separate service like this example from the documentation? 
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating two instances of TodoService, so data in these two component are different. In this case, you should share one instance through these components.

For Angular 6+ you can do it in service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

For Angular 2-5 you can do it in module:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [TodoService],
})
```

Here is more info about service provider - [Angular IO](https://angular.io/guide/providers.)

If this will not help, please share you module and service code.